# history back force refresh

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I have an application and when user is logged in (a cookie is present) in the dashboard, he can log out.
When he does so, he can hit history button on browser which takes him back to dashboard from cache.

If there any other way then a javascript cookie check (which has been removed after logout, and will force a document.location = '/' when cookie is not present) to force a reload of this page so it will automatically will be picked up by my serverside authentication check?

Cheers,

Mattijs

Comment: Did you try changing the cache headers?

Answer (score 4):

This is what my company uses to expire the page cache:
`<cfheader name="Expires" value="#GetHttpTimeString(Now())#">
<cfheader name="Pragma" value="no-cache">
<cfheader name="cache-control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate ">`

Comment: We've turned those into a custom tag to save typing.

Comment: We automatically inject these into every request so our devs don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Set headers to expire the page cache? These two headers should do the trick.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate

Expires: Thu, 29 Jul 2000 05:00:00 GMT // Any date in the past would do
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's not that answer that you expect, but you can set infinite loop (for example, with 10 sec interval), in which you can send AJAX request to your server, which knows about real state of cookies.